# Angular material mat-menu text does not fit

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using the mat-menu component from angular material. However, the content does not fit in to the menu.
I don't want to use mat-select, because i want to show a button with a different value than the values in the dropdown.

Now my question is, how can I show the full text in the menu? With any kind of multi line or tooltip?

```
   <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">{{row.menuShortText}}</button>
   <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
      <span mat-menu-item>This is a very long text that does not fit</span>
      <span mat-menu-item>this fits</span>
      <span mat-menu-item>this fits</span>
      <span mat-menu-item>this fits</span>
      <span mat-menu-item>this fits</span>
   </mat-menu>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If a tooltip is ok you can add it to the span:

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <span mat-menu-item matTooltip="This is a very long text that does not fit">
    This is a very long text that does not fit</span>
  <span mat-menu-item>this fits</span>
  ...
</mat-menu>
```

don't forget to import `MatTooltipModule`

Comment: Yes but I was hoping to have some other possibilities

Comment: Also `matTooltip` only accepts a string literal (which is kind of surprising...)